# Check for invalid keys JavaScript Firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I can retrieve a data in javascript
: `players.child(key).exists();` 
But nodejs return this warring

```
    FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. Error: Firebase.child failed: First 
argument was an invalid path: "". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#",
 "$", "[", or "]"                                                                            
    at Error (<anonymous>)                                                                   
    at gg (/var/node/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js:136:59)                      
    at T.u (/var/node/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js:246:216)                    
    at /var/node/server.js:24:19                                                             
    at Object.manager.shots.objIntegrity (/var/node/server.js:26:7)                          
    at /var/node/server.js:39:33                                                             
    at /var/node/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js:46:642                           
    at Bb (/var/node/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js:43:165)                      
    at xb (/var/node/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js:22:216)                      
    at yb (/var/node/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js:21:1260)                     

/var/node/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js:43                                      
ion(){N("Exception was thrown by user callback.",b.stack||"");throw b;},Math.f               
                                                                    ^                        
Error: Firebase.child failed: First argument was an invalid path: "". Paths must be non-empty
 strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"                                        
    at Error (<anonymous>)                                                                   
    at gg (/var/node/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js:136:59)                      
    at T.u (/var/node/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js:246:216)                    
    at /var/node/server.js:24:19                                                             
    at Object.manager.shots.objIntegrity (/var/node/server.js:26:7)                          
    at /var/node/server.js:39:33                                                             
    at /var/node/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js:46:642                           
    at Bb (/var/node/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js:43:165)                      
    at xb (/var/node/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js:22:216)                      
    at yb (/var/node/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js:21:1260)
```

My structure of data is

```
{
   players{
      -K5MOHoOKvxL8_tcRfmc{
         et...
      }
   }
}
```

Thanks you for your help

Vinc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `.child()` you cannot specify a key of either `"", ".", "#",
 "$", "[", or "]"`.

The error states that you're trying to pass in an empty string. To resolve this error you need to check for invalid keys.

```
function isValidKey(key) {
  var invalidKeys = { '': '', '$': '$', '.': '.', '#': '#', '[': '[', ']': ']' };
  return invalidKeys[key] === undefined;
}

var key = "";
var playersRef = new Firebase('<my-firebase-db>/players');
if (isValidKey(key)) { 
  playersRef.child(key).once('value', function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.exists());
  });
}
```

One thing to note from your original snippet, the `.exists()` function is for `DataSnapshots`, not `References`. To check if the data exists, you'll need to do a `.once()` call and check the `DataSnapshot` returned.